# synonym: AI -> Artificial Intelligence

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags

AI is short for artificial intelligence. So we should synonym it. https://law.stackexchange.com/tags/artificial-intelligence/synonyms

Answer (score -3):

**Dissenting opinion**: I find that adequate for a *tech-focused* SE-site, e. g. StackOverflow. AI (or [ai](https://law.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/ai)) in the field of law could mean, *beside* artificial intelligence:

- *ab initio*
- *ab intestato*
- *ab intra*
- *ab invito*
- *ab irato*
- *absit iniuria*
- *absit invidia*
- Accredited Investor (as defined in 501 (a) (4) under the Securities Act)
- accrued interest
- *actus iuridicus*
- *ad idem*
- *ad infinitum*
- *ad interim*
- Allotted Institute
- *animus iniurandi*
- annual (gross) income
- artificial insemination
- Authorized Inspector
- Authorized Institution (as defined in § 2 of the Banking Ordinance)
- authorized intermediary

This list is not exhaustive.  Concededly, presently the “buzzword” AI is prominently associated with *artifical intelligence*, especially for people not familiar with (business/medicine) law or Latin.

Comment: the tag was made because people actually tagged ai as shorthand for Artificial Intelligence

Comment: If there come to be any instances of people using the other abbreviations, we should consider it then, when we have data.